# Use stored proc parameters in Select dynamic SQL

Tags: dynamic-sql

This question may sound stupid... but hey ! I can't find the answer ! lol!!
I have this query that I need to convert to dynamic query:

```
INSERT INTO [SurveyInterface].[tblCEProcessingWorkingLCPSUF](
                  ParentId,
                  OperatingEntityNumber,
                  SurveyGroupCodeId,
                  ReferencePeriod,
                  SurveyCodeId,
                  StructureLevel )
 SELECT ParentId,
         RealOperatingEntityNumber AS OperatingEntityNumber,
         '71' AS SurveyGroupCodeId,
         '201906' AS ReferencePeriod,
         'ZM' AS SurveyCodeId,
         StructureLevel
  FROM  dbo.tblSUFGeneric201906
  WHERE ParentId <> RealOperatingEntityNumber;
```

It looks so simple !

```
 DECLARE @InputSurveyGroupCodeId INT = 71
            ,@InputReferencePeriod  VARCHAR(6) = '201906'
            ,@InputSurveyCodeId VARCHAR(2) = 'ZM'    
 EXEC ('INSERT INTO [SurveyInterface].[tblCEProcessingWorkingLCPSUF](
                  ParentId,
                  OperatingEntityNumber,
                  SurveyGroupCodeId,
                  ReferencePeriod,
                  SurveyCodeId,
                  StructureLevel )
    SELECT ParentId,
         RealOperatingEntityNumber AS OperatingEntityNumber,
           ' + @InputSurveyGroupCodeId + ' AS SurveyGroupCodeId,
           ' + @InputReferencePeriod + ' AS ReferencePeriod,
           ' + @InputSurveyCodeId + ' AS SurveyCodeId,
           StructureLevel
  FROM  ' + @InputSUFFrameTable + '
  WHERE ParentId <> RealOperatingEntityNumber')
```

But when I execute it, I get the folowing error message :
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 2, Procedure uspCEProcessingMainScriptAllProcesses, Line 634 [Batch Start Line 2]
Invalid column name 'ZM'.

Why is it working when the values are numbers, but not string ?  The only issue that I have is with the parameter "@InputSurveyCodeId".  I did tried the following:

```
' + quotename(@InputSurveyCodeId, '''') + ' AS SurveyCodeId
```

But then I got the error message : Incorrect syntax near 'quotename'.  Do you guys see something I don't ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help :-)
Mylene

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
DECLARE @sqlstatement NVARCHAR(max)
 SET @sqlstatement = 'INSERT INTO [SurveyInterface].tblCEProcessingWorkingLCPSUF](
         ParentId,
         OperatingEntityNumber,
         SurveyGroupCodeId,
         ReferencePeriod,
         SurveyCodeId,
         StructureLevel )
     SELECT ParentId,
            RealOperatingEntityNumber AS OperatingEntityNumber,
           ' + quotename(@InputSurveyGroupCodeId, '''') + ' AS SurveyGroupCodeId,
           ' + quotename(@InputReferencePeriod, '''') + ' AS ReferencePeriod,
           ' + quotename(@InputSurveyCodeId, '''') + ' AS SurveyCodeId,
            StructureLevel
     FROM  ' + @InputSUFFrameTable + '
     WHERE ParentId <> RealOperatingEntityNumber'
    
 PRINT @sqlstatement
 EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sqlstatement
```